# overall HTTP timeout for OkHttpClient

Tags: java, sockets, http, okhttp

is there a way to **interrupt a pending HTTP request** sent with OkHttpClient' `client.newCall(request).execute()` after a certain timeout by e.g. force closing the underlying socket?

I know that **socket connection and read/write timeouts** can be configured. But if the socket is established within the connection timeout and a (partial) response is received within the read timeout, the HTTP request might still not be "done".